# Draw P and S waves illustration

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

I need some help with drawing similar figures. Don't care about colour. Thanks.

[image: Body waves]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried something? If you did, you can post an example of code, it always help to answer the question.

Answer (score 28):

Welcome! This does something of that sort. The parameters are stored in pgf keys, and the wave form in a function called `wv`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade left,
left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!0]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(60:1cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},
    line cap=round,line join=round,font=\sffamily,
 declare function={wv(\x)=-1*ifthenelse(\x<\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/xcrit},1,0)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/amplitude}*sin(\x*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/omega});},
 pics/pln/.style={code={
  \tikzset{wave/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/##1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextX}{\pv{xmin}+\pv{step}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextY}{\pv{ymin}+\pv{step}}
  \draw[fill=\pv{fill}] (0,0) rectangle (\pv{xmax},\pv{ymax});
 \draw foreach \Y in {\pv{ymin},\nextY,...,\pv{ymax}}
  {(0,\Y) -- (\pv{xmax},\Y)}
 foreach \X in {\pv{xmin},\nextX,...,\pv{xmax}}
    {({\X+wv(\X)},0) --
    ({\X+wv(\X)},\pv{ymax})};
 }},wave/.cd,xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=1,xcrit/.initial=1,
    ymin/.initial=0,ymax/.initial=1,
    step/.initial=0.2,omega/.initial=150,amplitude/.initial=0.15,
    fill/.initial=none
 ]
 \path (0,0,0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{P wave};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 \draw (12/5,1,1) -- ++ (0,0,0.3) -- node[fill=white] {Compressions}
 (24/5,1,1.3) -- ++ (0,0,-0.3);
 \draw (18/5,0,0) -- ++ (0,0,-0.3) -- node[fill=white] {Dilations}
 (30/5,0,-0.3) -- ++ (0,0,0.3);
 %
 \path (0,0,-1) coordinate (L1) (7,0,-1) coordinate (R1); 
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,wave/.cd,xcrit=6]
  \path (0,0,-0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{S wave};
  \draw[fill=orange!50]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,1,{wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Y in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,\Y,{wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{wv(\X)}) -- (\X,1,{wv(\X)});} 
  % 
  \draw[fill=orange]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{+wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+\Z+wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{-1+wv(\X)}) -- (\X,0,{wv(\X)});} 
  %  
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9,yshift=-1cm]
   \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
  \end{scope} 
  \draw (15/5,0,{-1+wv(15/5)}) coordinate (auxtl)-- ++ (0,0,-0.8) coordinate (auxbl)
  (27/5,0,{-1+wv(27/5)}) coordinate (auxtr) -- ++ (0,0,-0.8) coordinate (auxbr)
  node[pos=0.5,left,inner ysep=1pt](amp) {Amplitude};
  \draw[densely dashed] (auxtl) --  (auxtr);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (21/5,0,{-1+wv(21/5)}) -- coordinate(aux) (21/5,0,{-1+wv(27/5)});
  \draw[-] (aux) -- (amp);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] ([yshift=1mm]auxbl) -- node[below]{Wavelength}
  ([yshift=1mm]auxbr);
  \path (2,0,-3.5) coordinate (L2) (9,0,-3.5) coordinate (R2);       
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L1) -- (R1);
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L2) -- (R2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to smoothen out the transition, this is also possible. However, if you want to employ simple smooth functions such as `tanh` for that purpose, you might need the `fpu` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,fadings,fpu}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{wv}{1}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{(tanh(2*(#1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/xcrit}))-1)*%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/amplitude}*sin(#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/omega})}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}

\tikzfading[name=fade left,
left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!0]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(60:1cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},
    line cap=round,line join=round,font=\sffamily,
 pics/pln/.style={code={
  \tikzset{wave/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/##1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextX}{\pv{xmin}+\pv{step}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextY}{\pv{ymin}+\pv{step}}
  \draw[fill=\pv{fill}] (0,0) rectangle (\pv{xmax},\pv{ymax});
 \draw foreach \Y in {\pv{ymin},\nextY,...,\pv{ymax}}
  {(0,\Y) -- (\pv{xmax},\Y)}
 foreach \X in {\pv{xmin},\nextX,...,\pv{xmax}}
    {({\X+wv(\X)},0) --
    ({\X+wv(\X)},\pv{ymax})};
 }},wave/.cd,xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=1,xcrit/.initial=1,
    ymin/.initial=0,ymax/.initial=1,
    step/.initial=0.2,omega/.initial=150,amplitude/.initial=0.1,
    fill/.initial=none
 ]
 \path (0,0,0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{P wave};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 \draw (12/5,1,1) -- ++ (0,0,0.3) -- node[fill=white] {Compressions}
 (24/5,1,1.3) -- ++ (0,0,-0.3);
 \draw (18/5,0,0) -- ++ (0,0,-0.3) -- node[fill=white] {Dilations}
 (30/5,0,-0.3) -- ++ (0,0,0.3);
 \draw (6,1,1) -- ++ (0,0,0.1) node[above right] {Undisturbed medium};
 %
 \path (0,0,-1) coordinate (L1) (7,0,-1) coordinate (R1); 
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,wave/.cd,xcrit=6,amplitude=0.15]
  \path (0,0,-0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{S wave};
  \draw[fill=orange!50]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,1,{wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Y in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,\Y,{wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{wv(\X)}) -- (\X,1,{wv(\X)});} 
  % 
  \draw[fill=orange]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{+wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+\Z+wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{-1+wv(\X)}) -- (\X,0,{wv(\X)});} 
  %  
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9,yshift=-1cm]
   \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
  \end{scope} 
  \draw (15/5,0,{-1+wv(15/5)}) coordinate (auxtl)-- ++ (0,0,-0.8) coordinate (auxbl)
  (27/5,0,{-1+wv(27/5)}) coordinate (auxtr) -- ++ (0,0,-0.8) coordinate (auxbr)
  node[pos=0.5,left,inner ysep=1pt](amp) {Amplitude};
  \draw[densely dashed] (auxtl) --  (auxtr);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (21/5,0,{-1+wv(21/5)}) -- coordinate(aux) (21/5,0,{-1+wv(27/5)});
  \draw[-] (aux) -- (amp);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] ([yshift=1mm]auxbl) -- node[below]{Wavelength}
  ([yshift=1mm]auxbr);
  \path (2,0,-3.5) coordinate (L2) (9,0,-3.5) coordinate (R2);       
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,sharp corners]
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L1) -- (R1);
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L2) -- (R2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This smooth version also looks better when animated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,fadings,fpu}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{wv}{1}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{(tanh(2*(#1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/xcrit}))-1)*%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/amplitude}*sin(#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/omega}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/phase})}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}
\tikzset{pics/pln/.style={code={
  \tikzset{wave/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave/##1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextX}{\pv{xmin}+\pv{step}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextY}{\pv{ymin}+\pv{step}}
  \draw[fill=\pv{fill}] (0,0) rectangle (\pv{xmax},\pv{ymax});
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (\pv{xmax},\pv{ymax});
 \draw foreach \Y in {\pv{ymin},\nextY,...,\pv{ymax}}
  {(0,\Y) -- (\pv{xmax},\Y)}
 foreach \X in {\pv{xmin},\nextX,...,\pv{xmax}}
    {({\X+wv(\X)},0) --
    ({\X+wv(\X)},\pv{ymax})};
 }},wave/.cd,xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=1,xcrit/.initial=1,
    ymin/.initial=0,ymax/.initial=1,
    step/.initial=0.2,omega/.initial=150,amplitude/.initial=0.1,
    fill/.initial=none,phase/.initial=0}
\tikzfading[name=fade left,
left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!0]
\begin{document}
\foreach \Phase in {0,20,...,340}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(60:1cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},
    line cap=round,line join=round,font=\sffamily,wave/phase=\Phase]
 \path (0,0,0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{P wave};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xmax=9,xcrit=6,fill=orange}};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9,wave/phase=0]
  \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
 \end{scope}
 %
 \path (0,0,-1) coordinate (L1) (7,0,-1) coordinate (R1); 
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,wave/.cd,xcrit=6,amplitude=0.15]
  \path (0,0,-0.5) node[left=1em,node font=\large]{S wave};
  \draw[fill=orange!50]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,1,{wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Y in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,\Y,{wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{wv(\X)}) -- (\X,1,{wv(\X)});} 
  % 
  \draw[fill=orange]
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+wv(\x)}) -- 
     plot[domain=9:0,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{+wv(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \foreach \Z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
   {\draw
     plot[domain=0:9,samples=101,smooth] (\x,0,{-1+\Z+wv(\x)});} 
  \foreach \X in {0.2,0.4,...,8.8}
   {\draw (\X,0,{-1+wv(\X)}) -- (\X,0,{wv(\X)});} 
  %  
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=9,yshift=-1cm,wave/phase=0]
   \pic[transform shape,fill=orange]{pln={xcrit=0,fill=orange!50}};
  \end{scope} 
  \path (2,0,-3.5) coordinate (L2) (9,0,-3.5) coordinate (R2);       
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,sharp corners]
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L1) -- (R1);
  \draw[blue!50,line width=4pt,-stealth,path fading=fade left] (L2) -- (R2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They are seismic body waves. P waves travel the fastest and arrive first, hence "Primary". S waves follows after. 

Thank you so much btw, these are excellent, you are very talented.

Comment: @NFS Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You should get paid for doing this.